# How come i need to make another file handle to read the same file again?

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x

I was playing around files with python, so i wrote this:

```
 ifh=open('2.txt','r')  
   for line in ifh:  
     print(line,end="")
 print("Done")
 #ifh=open('2.txt','r')
    for line in ifh:
      print(line)
```

The second loop does print the file only if i uncomment the second file handle.
Why is that?
Shouldn't it work without the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because after the first loop is finished, `ifh`'s current position is at the end of the file. At that point, there is no more data to read.

To read the data again, you need to use [`ifh.seek(0)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to move back to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to [seek](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) back to the beginning of the file using this:

```
ifh.seek(0)
```

When you `open` the file again for reading, it resets the file's current position to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You are at the end of the file when you print `Done`. you can do a `ifh.seek(0)` to get to the beginning again.

Answer (score 0):

Do: `ifh.seek(0)` before second loop.

Its because you read all lines from the file and `seek` method goes to the first byte of file, and you can read it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a closed loop ahead of the for-loop.

```
while True:
    for line in ifh:
        print(line,end=" ")
```